# Touch ID integration on iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

I am developing a new iOS app, on that if the user is idle for some time the app become locked and need to authenticate using Touch ID or password. This is the first time I am working with touch ID. Now I am facing some issues, they are :

1. Can I use the Touch ID of my iPhone and the password of my app to unlock the app ? (That is when the app become locked the authentication alert will show, user can authenticate using Touch ID, or if the user taps on the "Enter password" option I need to navigate to another page of my app where the user authentication done by using the app password)
2. Is it possible to remove the "cancel" button from the touch ID alertview?
3. On the first time the "Enter password" option on the touch ID alert is not showing. When I entered a wrong touch ID then from the next time onwards the Enter password option is displayed.
   (I didn't set any value for "localizedFallbackTitle")

Comment: For starters see this  http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the Touch ID of my iPhone and the password of my app to
>   unlock the app ? (That is when the app become locked the
>   authentication alert will show, user can authenticate using Touch ID,
>   or if the user taps on the "Enter password" option I need to navigate
>   to another page of my app where the user authentication done by using
>   the app password)

You can bring up the Touch ID dialog when your app auto-locks but I wouldn't. Based on some testing I did while back the Touch ID dialog must be dismissed or unlocked, you can't press the Home button to go to another app. I also believes it auto-cancels after some time period. A much better design would be to put up a "I'm locked" screen with an "unlock" button, which would raise the Touch ID dialog when tapped.

> Is it possible to remove the "cancel" button from the touch ID alertview?

Not that I'm aware of, I wanted to do the same thing.

> On the first time the "Enter password" option on the touch ID alert is
>   not showing. When I entered a wrong touch ID then from the next time
>   onwards the Enter password option is displayed. (I didn't set any
>   value for "localizedFallbackTitle")

This appears to be the correct behavior. I think this started with iOS8.2.